# Prove that a parabolic problem is well posed (Lax-Milgram lemma appilication)

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, solution-verification, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

I need a check on the following problem, which is an application of the Lax-Milgram lemma.
$$
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t} -\dfrac{\partial }{\partial x} \Bigl( \alpha \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}\Bigr) - \beta u =0 \\
u(x,0)=u_0(x), & x \in [0,1] \\
u = \eta, & x=0,\; t>0 \\
\alpha \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \gamma u =0, & x=1,\; t>0
\end{cases}
$$
where $\alpha(x), u_0(x)$ are given functions, $\beta >0$ and $\eta,\gamma \in \mathbb{R}$.

**Question. Prove existence and uniqueness of the weak solution, giving some suitable assumptions on  $\alpha(x)$,$\gamma, \eta$**.

---

**Here's my attempt:**

As test functions, I choose $v \in V=H_{\Gamma_d}^1$, where $\Gamma_d={0}$,i.e. I use tes functions which are $0$ where I have the Dirichlet data. By multiplying, with standard arguments one obtains the following bilinear form $$a(u,v)=\gamma u(1)v(1) + \int_0^1 \alpha u' v' dx - \beta \int_0^1 u v dx$$

To show existence and uniqueness, I need to show

- $a(v,v) + \lambda \geq \alpha \|v\|_V^2$ (weakly coercive)
- $a(u,v) \leq M \|u\|_V \|v\|_V$

*Weakly coercive*:
Assume $0<\alpha_0 < \alpha(x) < \alpha_1$
$$a(v,v) + \beta \|v\|_V^2 \geq \frac{\alpha_0}{1+C_p^2} \|v\|_V^2 + \gamma v(1)^2$$

where $C_p$ is the Poincarè constant.
If $\gamma >0$, then:
$$a(v,v) + \beta \|v\|_V^2 \geq \frac{\alpha_0}{1+C_p^2} \|v\|_V^2$$
i.e. $a(\cdot, \cdot)$ is weakly coercive.

*Continuity*:

$$|a(u,v)| \leq \alpha_1 \|u\|_V \|v\|_V + \beta \|u\|_V \|v\|_V + \gamma u(1)v(1)$$

Now, since I want a bound with the $H^1$ norm, I note that $$|u(1)| \leq \int_0^1 |u'(s)|ds + \eta$$ and therefore $$|u(1)| \leq \|u\|_V + \eta$$ Also, $v(1) = \int_0^1 v'(s)ds$ implies $|v(1)| \leq \|v\|_V$

Hence, $$|a(u,v)| \leq (\alpha_1 + \beta) \|u\|_V \|v\|_V+\gamma \|u\|_V \|v\|_V + \gamma \eta \|v\|_V $$

Now, if $\eta <0$, then $$|a(u,v)| \leq (\alpha_1+\beta+\gamma)\|u\|_V \|v\|_V$$

Comment: My comment may be misplaced, but I have some queries about your "weak coercivity". In Babuska's generalisation of Lax - Milgram, coercivity is replaced with inf-sup stability. Is your weak coercivity really equivalent to this, especially considering your test and trial spaces are not equal? And for continuity, I would think that $\|u \|_V$ should be replaced by a norm on your trial space as $u\notin V$.